# How to test a IBAction and Selector in ObjC

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm confused on how to create a unit test to validate a IBAction method is called and also to test a selector.

For example I have this code.

```
- (IBAction)tapButton:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
       //do something 
 }
```

This code is for selector

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(tapButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

- (void)tapButton:(id)sender {
       //do something
}
```

I have this unit test.

```
- (void)test_tapAction {
   ClassView *view = [ClassView alloc] init];
   id mock = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:view];
   [[mock expect] tapButton:[OCMArg any]];
   [mock tapButton:[OCMArg any]];
   OCMVerify([mock tapButton:[OCMArg any]]);
   [mock stopMocking];
}
```

But I'm not sure this is the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

I get the solution.
The code about the test it's not bad but have a mistake in this line.

```
[[mock expect] tapButton:[OCMArg any]];
```

This line doesn't call the method I want to test

> - (IBAction)tapButton:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender

In conclusion the code about unit test looks like this:

```
- (void)test_tapCreditsAction {
   ClassView *view = [ClassView alloc] init];
   id mock = [OCMockObject partialMockForObject:view];
   [mock tapButton:[OCMArg any]];
   OCMVerify([mock tapButton:[OCMArg any]]);
   [mock stopMocking];
  }
```

This is the correct way to test an IBAction or selector.